# Error in MySQL function with parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, function, sql-function, mysql-function

I have MySQL function with **2 parameters** namely **user_id** and **post_id**

Here's my function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION isliked(pid INT, uid INT)
RETURN TABLE
AS
RETURN (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM likedata ld WHERE post_id = pid AND user_id = uid
       )) as is_liked
END
```

I tried to call it with below query:

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.title, isliked(111,123)
FROM posts
```

It returns the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RETURN TABLE
AS
RETURN (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM likedata ld WHERE post_id = pid AN' at line 2
```

It should be return results like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91040/5
I'm new to sql, any help will be great, thanks in advance

Comment: your function have syntax problem. go the office mysql site and find the syntax of what's actual does syntax and make the appropriate changes

Comment: Don't you have 2 '(' in your  function but 3 ')' ?

Comment: You probably want to return a Boolean/bit rather than a table. You only need one value and it looks like you want to use it in the select clause.

Comment: Yes please check my code and  help @Horia Coman

Comment: What is the expected output? What do you want isliked function to return?

Comment: It will return Boolean value i.e. if liked then 1 else 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the function to return Boolean value use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION isliked(pid INT, uid INT)
RETURNS BIT
   RETURN ( EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM likedata ld WHERE post_id = pid AND user_id = uid ) )
```